# Extarcting the service name and timstamp from a log file

Tags: shell

I have a log file output that I am getting after I run the grep command.
For example:

> 2019-01-30 08:58:05.386 -0800 INFO [16168] - Program Ended:
>   xxx::xxxxxx::xxxxxxxx::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxx
>   [Test1.Demo.v1.0_Final] [xxxxxxx] pid 16168 user dexter after 00:06:29

So I need a shell/perl/python script that can fetch the Text inside [] i.e Test1.Demo.v1.0_Final and also print the time stamp i.e. 00:06:29 (this is the time that it took to run)

Any help will be appreciated!!

Thanks

So this output should be send to a txt or csv file stating 
ServiceName     |   Timestamp
Test1.Demo.V1.0    00:06:29

Comment: Can you help me with the same thing using python script??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely there are better and more elegant solutions, but this can do it :

```
var1=$(cat log.file | cut -d'[' -f3- | cut -d']' -f1)
var2=$(cat log.file | grep -o -P 'after.{0,9}'| cut -d' ' -f2)
result="$var1 $var2"
echo $result
```

Test1.Demo.v1.0_Final 00:06:29

`var1` gets the first part "Test1.Demo..."
 and `var2` gets the timestamp. Finally `result` is concatenating `var1` and `var2`

for searching in multiple files you can wrap this in some loops like :

```
result=""
for f in $(find /path/to/your/logs -name 'Logfile*'); do
   while read line; do
     if echo "$line" | grep -q 'Program Ended'; then
        var1=$(cat "$line" | cut -d'[' -f3- | cut -d']' -f1)
        var2=$(cat "$line" | grep -o -P 'after.{0,9}'| cut -d' ' -f2)
        result+="$var1 $var2\n"
     fi
   done < $f
done
echo -e "$result"
```

I haven't tested this but it should be ok I believe and give you an idea on how to proceed

Comment: Thanks man that worked! although i have an small issue i have a dir logs that contains all the logfile names for example: Logfile1, logfile1 etc, so i have to grep through each log file for a pattern called "Program Ended" this will give me that output above, hence after fetching all the timestamp and logfile names i need to calculate the average time taken......the log file names actually are the service names and i need to extract the timeinfo and service name to calculate the average time taken by all the services so that i can provide an better extimate.....any suggestions will be helpfull

Comment: if my suggestion helped you then please accept it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Ok can you also help me with my second issue?

Comment: Hello, I appreciate all your help just wanted to make the point much clear suppose i have log files with diff names ok so like you mentioned for f in $(find /path/to/your/logs -name 'Logfile*'); do in this case i am assuming that you though the file names must be same but it isn't so how should i fetch from those log files. They have names like Analytic.Partners.DVRMarket15Minute.v1.0_Final, DemoMarket15Minute.v1.2a_Political,DemoMarket15Minute.v1.2a...etc...rest is good i.e searching for patterns......so what pattern should i use for these log files?

Comment: I don't know what pattern you should use, I don't know all your log file names. If all of them are inside a single directory you can use this find instead : `find /path/to/your/logs -type f`

Comment: Can you help me with the same thing using python?